# Undefined variable: kelas

Tags: php, laravel

How do I get a value of JSON to variable kelas?
Here I found the error undefined variable kelas

```
public function tahunForKelas($tahun_id)

    {
       $siswa_json = DB::table('siswa')->select(['siswa.id_siswa'])
           ->join('nilai','nilai.id_siswa','=','siswa.id_siswa')
           ->join('waliMurid','waliMurid.id_siswa','=','siswa.id_siswa')
           ->where('waliMurid.id_waliMurid','=',Auth::guard('orangtua')->user()->id_waliMurid)->get();


           foreach ($siswa_json as $siswa) {

               $id_siswa = $siswa->id_siswa;

         $kelas = DB::table('kelas')->select(['kelas.id_kelas','kelas.nama_kelas'])->join('kelasSiswa','kelasSiswa.id_kelas','=','kelas.id_kelas')->where('kelasSiswa.id_siswa',$id_siswa)->where('kelasSiswa.id_tahun',$tahun_id)->get();
           }



      return Response::json($kelas);
   }
```

Comment: That's because your `$siswa_json` is empty so it never gets into the `foreach` loop. Therefore, your `$kelas` has never been defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because your query builder return empty value. You must create condition if its empty, so it won't throw an undefined error.

```
if (!empty($siswa_json)) {
    foreach ($siswa_json as $siswa) {
        $id_siswa = $siswa->id_siswa;

        $kelas = DB::table('kelas')->select(['kelas.id_kelas','kelas.nama_kelas'])->join('kelasSiswa','kelasSiswa.id_kelas','=','kelas.id_kelas')->where('kelasSiswa.id_siswa',$id_siswa)->where('kelasSiswa.id_tahun',$tahun_id)->get();
    }
} else {
    $kelas = [];
}
```